# Outlook rules working only partially

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2016, exchange-2016

I have outlook rules which have 10+ email recipients/senders in their condition to apply.
An example is 'Apply this rule to all emails from A, B, C..., except if sent to N1,N2...N20'.

What is now happening with my rules is that when email arrives, even if the recipient is part of exception list, the rule applies to email and I am essentially loosing on reading those emails.

Is it possible that too many email addresses in 1 condition of rule would cause this or there could be some other reason?

I need to mention that the rule works correctly for some of the recipients in the exception list, while for other's it does not and I can not figure out what would be the reason for this behavior.

Rules are server side so they should work even without Outlook running, but that's not the case.

Comment: Rules are applied consecutively, so check the sequence , duplicates and for logic errors in rules.

Comment: The troubling rule is first in list, so it should execute every time.
I don't have duplicates, essentially the rule is sort of master rule of what to throw away and what not, then there are other rules applying categories and flags. Those work as expected.

The problem seems to be that only for certain mail addresses in exception list the rule ignores them, while others are considered.

Comment: Have you added condition" stop process more rules"? In case there were something wrong with the rule. we can recreate the rule. If there are too many recipients, we may slipt it to two rules to test the results.

Comment: I can’t add stop processing more rules because I need to to go through all rules until the end. I thought of splitting it into more rules but that doesn’t solve problem really and doesn’t give me the required logic.

Comment: the option "stop processing more rules " is normally used to avoid rule conflicts instead of only run this rule.